# How can I stop a navigation while keeping pop up modal on the screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, href

On my page I have a button object declared as below.

`<a class="button class" href="www.sometargeturl.com" onclick="makevisibile()">`

The javascript `makevisible()` function just makes a `<div>` tag visible which acts then like a modal popup.

When the user hits the button, the the popup is displayed but after one second the user is navigated to sometargeturl.com.  What I want is the popup to stop the navigation process until the user closes it, or clicks outside of it, only then do I want the navigation to resume.

Is this possible with plain html/css and javascript or do I have to use some fancy framework?

Cheers,
Bob

Comment: Well you do not cancel the click

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent the default action by using `return false;`:

```
<a class="button class" href="www.sometargeturl.com" onclick="makevisibile();return false;">
```

Or put `return false` as the last line of your `makevisible()` function:

```
<a class="button class" href="www.sometargeturl.com" onclick="return makevisibile();">

function makevisibile(){
    // ....
    return false;
}
```

Comment: so this solution will stop the navigation all together I believe, the intent is however to resume navigation automatically to target URL once popup lis closed.  Can this be achieved?Thanks,Bob

Comment: Yes, you are correct, this prevents the browser from taking its normal action. In order to navigate to target URL, you'll need to hook onto some action (like the "close" button click in the pop up window) with `window.location='http://www.sometargeturl.com/';`

Comment: Thanks, I just tried appending like : onclick="makevisibile();return false; but it still navigates to the URL.  Am I missing something?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the contents of your `makevisibile()` function, which may contain an error that may be preventing the JavaScript from continuing to execute in your browser. The example works at http://jsfiddle.net/hr20yj9f/

Answer (score 0):

You want to prevent the default behaviour of the link (which is to navigate away).

You can either use another element instead of `href` for example a `button` or a code snippet similar to the one @Set Sail Media have suggested.

Keep in mind that in both cases you will manually need to change the url to the right location when the user closes the "pop-up".

**EDIT 1**

Bob, like you pointed out in your comments, if you disable the default behaviour of the `href` the page will not change when the user closes the pop-up window.

Let's assume you have a close function for the modal window which is called, `close_modal()` and it is called then the user closes the "pop-up"

```
function close_modal()
{
document.location='http://www.example.com';
}
```

You do NOT need to make a separate function for this, it all depends on how your page is currently looking.

For a better more complex answer please post a jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks but I don't know what you mean by "need to change url to the right location when the user closes the "pop-up".  Could you please elaborate?

Comment: `document.location=''` does not work in IE browser; instead should be using `window.location=''`